# How to transform SVG Path

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg

I'm using SVG path to draw connection lines between two Angular Material tree components. I have a problem because when I expand tree nodes the path moves up or down but I want it to stay in the same position. And when I collapse tree nodes I want to move paths from child nodes to parent node.

I have tried to transform: translate or matrix but I didn't know how to calculate values.

Should I use transform or edit "d" attribute of path??

This is how I create svg:

```
createSVG() {
  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-main-container');
  this.svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");                                                    
  this.svg.setAttribute('id', 'svg-canvas');
  this.svg.setAttribute('style', `position:absolute;left:0;top:0;display:inline-block;height:100%;width:100%`);
  this.svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 100 100');
  this.svg.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
  this.svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
  svgContainer.appendChild(this.svg);
  this.svgService.svg = this.svg;
  return this.svg;
}
```

This is how I draw connection path:

```
drawConnector(a,b){
  let path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
  let d = `M${a.x_left},${a.y_left} C50,${a.y_left} 50 ${b.y_right} ${b.x_right} ${b.y_right}`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#555");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "1.5px");
  path.setAttributeNS(null, "vector-effect", "non-scaling-stroke");
  path.setAttribute("id", this.svgService.draggedElementId);
  path.setAttribute("class", this.svgService.draggedElementId);
  this.svgService.svg.appendChild(path);
}
```

How I connect elements:

```
connectDivs(leftId, rightId, color, tension) {

  leftId = this.svgService.draggedElementId
  rightId = this.svgService.droppedElementId

  this.svgService.connections.push({leftId,rightId});

  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-component');
  let mainBox = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

  let points = [];

  //left element
  let left = document.getElementById(leftId);
  let leftPosition = left.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x_left = this.mapCoordinates(leftPosition.left - mainBox.left + leftPosition.width/2, mainBox.left, mainBox.left + mainBox.width, 0, 100);
  let y_left = this.mapCoordinates(leftPosition.top - mainBox.top + leftPosition.height/2, mainBox.top, mainBox.top + mainBox.height, 0, 100);

  points.push({x_left, y_left});

  //right element
  let right = document.getElementById(rightId);
  let rightPosition = right.getBoundingClientRect()
  let x_right = this.mapCoordinates(rightPosition.left - mainBox.left + rightPosition.width/2, mainBox.left, mainBox.left + mainBox.width, 0, 100);
  let y_right = this.mapCoordinates(rightPosition.top - mainBox.top + rightPosition.height/2, mainBox.top, mainBox.top + mainBox.height, 0, 100);
  points.push({x_right, y_right});

  this.drawConnector(points[0], points[1]);
}
```

And how I tried to transform path when tree is expanded:

```
expandLines(node){
  let nodeElement = document.getElementById(node.id);
  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-main-container');
  let svgBox = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  let nodePosition = nodeElement.getBoundingClientRect() //position of collapsed/expanded tree element
  let x_node = this.mapCoordinates(nodePosition.left - svgBox.left + nodePosition.width/2, svgBox.left, svgBox.left + svgBox.width, 0, 100);
  let y_node = this.mapCoordinates(nodePosition.top - svgBox.top + nodePosition.height/2, svgBox.top, svgBox.top + svgBox.height, 0, 100);

  let svgCanvas = document.getElementById('svg-canvas');
  let svgCanvasBox = svgCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  let path = svgCanvas.getElementsByClassName(node.id)[0];
  let pathPosition = path.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x_path = this.mapCoordinates(pathPosition.left - svgCanvasBox.left + pathPosition.width/2, svgCanvasBox.left, svgCanvasBox.left + svgCanvasBox.width, 0, 100);
  let y_path = this.mapCoordinates(pathPosition.top - svgCanvasBox.top + pathPosition.height/2, svgCanvasBox.top, svgCanvasBox.top + svgCanvasBox.height, 0, 100);

  let trans_x = x_path + x_node;
  let trans_y = y_path - y_node;

  //path.setAttribute('transform',`translate(${trans_x}, ${trans_y})`);
  path.setAttribute('transform', `matrix(1,0,0,1,${trans_x},${trans_y})`);
}

mapCoordinates(n, a, b, _a, _b){
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

Images of what I have:

[How my tree with path look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkQPc.png)

[What happen when I expand tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUK1D.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining a `viewBox` attribute with a `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. This has the effect that the `<svg>` element, which is set always to fill the height of the containing element, constantly re-scales the meaning of all coordinates inside the SVG if the size of the container changes.

When often the advice is to add a viewBox, in your special case, leaving off these two attributes will actually help. The coordinate system of the `<svg>` element itself (the "initial viewport") and the coordinate system of its content (the "initial user coordinate system") are two [different entities](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#Introduction):

> Each SVG viewport generates a viewport coordinate system and a user coordinate system, initially identical. Providing a `viewBox` on a viewport's element transforms the user coordinate system relative to the viewport coordinate system...

Only without a `viewBox` attribute, the two coordinate systems coincide even when the `<svg>` element changes its size.

When you have coordinates that are related to content outside the SVG, like your `a, b` parameters are, they only have a chance to remain meaningfull when the tree size changes if there is no coordinate transformation inbetween.

Your code does some coordinate transformation by hand to get from screen viewport coordinates to a supposed 100 * 100 viewBox. Remove all that. What you need is the relative vertical positions of your connected items to the `<svg>` element. Horizontally, you only go to the sides of your `<svg>`:

```
connectDivs(leftId, rightId, color, tension) {

  leftId = this.svgService.draggedElementId
  rightId = this.svgService.droppedElementId

  this.svgService.connections.push({leftId,rightId});

  let svgContainer = document.getElementById('svg-component');
  let mainBox = svgContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

  let points = [];

  //left element
  let left = document.getElementById(leftId);
  let leftPosition = left.getBoundingClientRect();
  // you always want the left side of the <svg> element
  let x_left = 0;
  let y_left = leftPosition.top - mainBox.top + leftPosition.height/2;

  points.push({x_left, y_left});

  //right element
  let right = document.getElementById(rightId);
  let rightPosition = right.getBoundingClientRect();
  // the right side of the <svg> element
  let x_right = mainBox.width;
  let y_right = rightPosition.top - mainBox.top + rightPosition.height/2;

  this.drawConnector(points[0], points[1]);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so when I expand the tree, size of the svg container changes so that's why my lines changes position. But without viewBox svg doesn't scale properly on window resize.
"a" and "b" parameters hold values of tree element's position which are connected.

Comment: do you know how can I achive properly scaling of svg without viewBox attribute so my lines won't move when the tree size changes?

Comment: The point is not scaling the svg _content_, but only the `<svg>` _element_ itself, which is achieved by setting `height:100%; width:100%`.

Comment: Each time the position should change, recompute the path as in your `drawConnector` method and change the attribute.

Comment: But when I don't have viewBox, paths are not drawed in the position that they should but in the top left corner.

Comment: I cannot comment on that unless I know what the numbers are that describe the element's positions. Which coordinate system are they expressed in?

Comment: Elements which I want to connect are outside the svg. In 'connectDivs' method I found their position in user coordinate system and call drawConnector method where I draw path based on this element's position (a and b have x and y position of element form left and right tree)